# typescript conditional type on generic

Tags: typescript

I have a type in a shape like this (simplified):

```
type AllContentType =
    | 'application/json'
    | 'application/octet-stream'
    | 'multipart/form-data';

type myType<T = AllContentType> = {
    body: T extends 'multipart/form-data' ? number : string;
    otherHeader: T;
};
```

and it cannot figure out which string has been put into `otherHeader`, it always returns

```
const obj: myType = { header: 'multipart/form-data', body: ""  };
```

`body` as `string | number`. Any way to get it to figure out what I actually have put in?

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAwgewHbAugKuaBeAWACgBIAHygHIBDMMOASwGNrgG0B6AKwGc1Li5KrXrNW7VB2RMMwALQ9gAJwjUAtgNIVKagK5w2YakuAcAZsiVq5AE1bVKAbmLFQkKGpA5IAHixQ8WAQUdExgbwgAPgCoAG9BACNkGxAALih-CAAPDFQbHio9AwYjE3NLaztgBygAfihUXTUEiCUodMUlBlQAc2dSAAtVG1b0rH6AX37iJjRFKGQErnTPCJjYqCHqEaV0nX1DY1MLK1t7SgAaKCSU9IAiO6goKZciYg4OKAA5ZGAoHgYalEZgYEBsUDcEFSr0hsF0wAGADEIMAmAMAJKoMDwvxQbK5fJBJBoXLhXAxeDE0LYXDRQIACkEFHipBIJDUKIGyVqewACgB5ADKWCcgjZNzSGTxOUwhP2xVKxwqZ2qlDqUERFQAIvZ2lAAEoQWZKGw%20TrdHpXXSoADWqGQAHdUJF%20iQnhMmXExezOdy9gBxACiIqg2i1gYAMsHA6LSO7iABKKAAMi9pF0SjgPKgAFV9RHXVsdjxsyy2ZQQqS5BFKGNXS8iFMgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By giving your type parameter a default value

```
type myType<T = AllContentType>
```

writing this

```
const obj: myType = { otherHeader: 'multipart/form-data', body: ""  };
```

is effectively

```
const obj: myType<AllContentType> = { otherHeader: 'multipart/form-data', body: ""  };
```

which makes the predicate `T extends 'multipart/form-data'` false.

If you leave out the default value for the type parameter and specify the type explicitly, it would work properly:

```
type myType<T extends AllContentType> = {
  body: T extends 'multipart/form-data' ? number : string;
  otherHeader: T;
};

const obj: myType<'multipart/form-data'> = { otherHeader: 'multipart/form-data', body: "" };
```

although that adds repetition.

Comment: And there is no way to get that repetition out, right?

Comment: @Twiggeh If you use `myType<T>` as a parameter of a function, then you can make type inference do the job. But if you're defining a property, variable, etc. you'll have to specify the type explicitly.